# Difference between import * as firebase and import firebase from "firebase/app"

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

From firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) we can see the following:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics
import "firebase/analytics";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

What is the difference between the two imports below:

- `import * as firebase from "firebase/app";`
- `import firebase from "firebase/app";`

What am I importing in the 1st one that I'm not importing in the 2nd one? What should I use one over the other?

**Note:** I don't know if it matters, but I do use Typescript.

Comment: Side note: You can't use markdown in titles. I've suggested an edit to remove it.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I know it doesn't actually work, but at least it separates the code parts from regular words and it's less confusing to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `import * from name`, you are importing all the modules exported in that file. In `import name`, the default module exported from the file is imported into `name`, and the default module is the only one in a single file.

Comment: Thanks, sheikh. I would like to know more about what this means specifically for the `firebase/app` package. Exactly what packages are being imported in that `import *` declaration.